# LibreOffice Base crashes on 32bit arch for 16.04 and 17.04

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, 17.04, 32-bit

I launch LibreOffice base, create a new base, use all the default (HSQLDB), just click next, OK, chose a file name, click OK, and it crashes.

> soffice.bin crashed with SIGSEGV

It is a 32-bit machine, It crashes with 16.04 (tried OpenJDK 8.131 and Oracle Java 8.144 and tried updating LO to latest version), it crashes also with the newest 17.04, fully updated.

I tried on a physical machine and on another one in VirtualBox.

It does **not** crash using a **64bit** install.

Any hint??

Answer (score 3):

I finally found some info. Issue started mid June 2017.

- LibreOffice Base does not work on a 32 bit Linux machine
- It should be fixed with a new kernel release (hopefully)
- It is a change in the kernel (security fix) that affected Java that is required for LibreOffice Base
- Neither Ubuntu or LibreOffice or OpenJDK can fix this kernel issue (OK, maybe OpenJDK could also fix it)
- There IS a **workaround** (tested on 16.04 and 17.04): "Add kernel parameter `stack_guard_gap=1`"

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and change the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to include the parameter, for example after your edit it may look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash stack_guard_gap=1"
```

then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

You should remove this parameter when the new kernel solve the issue (test), because I guess is it less secure without stack_guard ...

References:

- The [Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1699772)
- The [LibreOffice bug report](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108619)
- A [Linux Kernel Mailing List post](https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/7/3/1008) by Ben Hutchings
- [Problematic code](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org/msg1437925.html)

Looks like I cannot post more than 2 Links here. But complete answer is [here at ask.libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/120447/libreoffice-base-32bit-crashes-tried-multiple-configurations/?answer=120463#post-id-120463).